# Checkbox in datagrid view in Window form in C#

Tags: c#

I create the checkbox column in datagrid. and it works fine. But i need to select or fire the click event to whole the checkbox column with another checkbox outside the datagrid.I tried it but it just checked the checkbox but it doesn't fire the click event within the cells containing the checkbox. SO is there any solution?please help

Comment: Maybe you should paste some code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the grid and set the value as shown for the column concerned in the checked event of the other checkbox

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow var in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    var.Cells[3].Value = true;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , it works fine after some modification,but what i need was the index of each rows too